# How to enable/access the Confluence API from a Confluence Server running in a Docker container

Tags: rest, docker, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am running a Confluence server using the official Docker container: `atlassian/confluence-server`: https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/confluence-server/

I would like now to access the Confluence REST API: https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest-server/

I see that the container exposes 2 ports: `8090` and `8091`. I can get the Confluence UI on the former. Is the latter supposed to be an API port?

I have checked also the plugins if I have to install a plugin. But I haven't found anything.

Maybe I have to send more variables or expose more ports from the `docker` command?

Comment: Just in case anybody is wondering (like me), what port 8091 is used for and then stumbles over this Stackoverflow question: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/docker-atlassian-confluence-server/pull-requests/8/confdev-48917-expose-port-8091-for/diff (CONFDEV-48917 - expose port 8091 for Synchrony), info about Synchrony: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confeap/administering-collaborative-editing-847355676.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The API need no further configuration. It is available on the same port as the UI. So, in the case of the default configuration of the `atlassian/confluence-server`, the API is available under:

```
http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content
```